# Visual studio addin - finding current solution folder path

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-addins

I have an add-in loaded, and a solution loaded, how would I find the folder path of that solution programmatically in C# in my addin?

Comment: programmatically, this is a real question.

Comment: Then you need to rephrase your question better, only after reading through it 4 more times, I understood what you are looking for.

Comment: @leppie: in what way is this not real and relevant. I no longer know the answer, or I'd answer it. Some property of the Solution object, I think.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Alas I figured it out after a lot of goooogling!!

In connect.cs:

```
    public String SolutionPath()
    {
        return Path.GetDirectoryName(_applicationObject.Solution.FullName);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The Solution.FullName answer is correct, but take care, you cannot access it until the OnStartupCompleted method is called in connect.cs.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code:

```
string solutionpath = Directory.GetParent(Application.ExecutablePath).Parent.Parent.Parent.FullName;
```

regards