# How to get Visual Studio Project (which is loaded in solution explorer) location via a Visual Studio Addin?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, add-in

I am developing a Visual Studio Addin using C#. I want to determine the location on file system of a solution or a project whichever is loaded in Visual Studio, using my Addin that is also loaded.

Please suggest as how i can do this? pointer to any resource will be helpful.

Thanks

Steve

Comment: You might try this...
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633985/visual-studio-addin-finding-current-solution-folder-path

Comment: Thanks. But i cant mark the comment as answer. Could you please post its as an answer so that i could mark it, please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the GetDirectoryName function in the System.IO.Path namespace should get you what you need.

```
public String SolutionPath()
{
    return Path.GetDirectoryName(_applicationObject.Solution.FullName);
}
```

This was also answered here...
[Visual studio addin - finding current solution folder path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633985/visual-studio-addin-finding-current-solution-folder-path)