# How to add files in solution explorer of visual studio?

Tags: c#, add-in

How to get the path of solution explorer of visual studio 2010 programmatically(Without Hard Coding)  using c# during addin development?So that we can add files under active project folder residing within solution explorer?

For example
During addin development,if we are creating a file,Visual studio **saves the files** in this *C:\Users\user_name\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\project_name*programatically using **AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;**.But I want to save the file, one level ahead.i.e in
*C:\Users\user_name\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\project_name\project_name*.So I want to know how to do this programmatically(using visual studio api's) in c# ?

Comment: Please don't double post. In your previous question, a question has been linked that has an answer. Please read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do

```
public String SolutionPath()
{
    return Path.GetDirectoryName(_applicationObject.Solution.FullName);
}
```

Gotten from: [Visual studio addin - finding current solution folder path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633985/visual-studio-addin-finding-current-solution-folder-path)

Comment: Thanks "Precious 1tj" for your help.I tried and I got the solution.Whole process works as follows.The above code gives the path till  the name of the main Solution Directory within which the project directory exists in visual studio,i:e if we have a solution named "one".using the above code ,file will be inserted inside the main solution directory.To add the file inside the project directory,we have to append project name which is one level down,then add  the file within it.Then only the file will be added to project directory and the file will appear in "solution explorer in visual studio"

Comment: yes.Whatever I wrote above as a comment'is the answer.As I am new using this site,I dont know how to mark it as answer.Can you tell me,how to mark a particular comment as answer?

Comment: is it the  tick mark  above? Do we have to click on it or wat?